# Asterisk exten Playback sound for different dialplan

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I have below dialplan where I am trying to play a sound like thursday which is skipping, but when I put evening the it says properly.

```html
exten => *7000,1,NoCDR()
exten => *7000,n,Answer()
exten => *7000,n,System(/bin/cp /etc/asterisk/extensions_custom_WEEKEND_TEMPLATE.conf /etc/asterisk/extensions_custom_ACTIVE.conf)
exten => *7000,n,Wait(1)
exten => *7000,n,System('/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "dialplan reload"')
exten => *7000,n,Playback(beep)
exten => *7000,n,Playback(thursday)
exten => *7000,n,Playback(service)
exten => *7000,n,Playback(activated)
exten => *7000,n,HangUp
```

And can we play the sound using the same voice as in freepbx lady voice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Freepbx lady" is Allison Smith, she offer record any sound file for additional money. http://theivrvoice.com/

What you described seams like incorrect file format.

Also whole dialplan is very bad design, reload dialplan for every dialplan rush is VERY VERY bad idea.Imagine what will be when 3 calls come in same moment.

Use asterisk REALTIME extensions architecture(dialplan from db) or db lookup for file name via func_odbc.

Comment: **arheops**, I thought Allison Smith voice is a tool inside/bundled with Freepbx so simply we can put the text and play that in?

Comment: No, Allison is real person. You can use cepstral.com allison 8khz text2speech voice, but it much less qualify as any other syntetic voice. Also freepbx is WEB INTERFACE, it have no binary tools inside.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your answer.